# Confusion with cookie session token and oauth2.0 don't know where to go anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm completely confused, frustrated and nothing seems to make sense and work any more.
I' dev some iframe fb app and i've been using the javascript sdk (FB.Init()) to get the access_token, but doesn't always work, sometimes i'm already logged into FB and doesn't works...

Did some reading, and read also that there is problems using cookies in iframes in Opera and IE, so I was thinking in use the OAuth 2.0 but i'm not sure how via facebook sdk c# and now I'm now completely lost, don't know if i still need to use the javascript FB.Init(). Documentation out there is poor and unclear, a lot of stuff refers to old code, and after hours of reading, jumping on examples, i'm completely messed up and confused.

Can some, please, point/explain/enlightening me about this?

Thanks a lot guys, appreciated!

Merry christmas!

Comment: Are you building an MVC or Web Forms app?

Comment: Actualy it can be both...i'm just wrapping up everything i need into a new dll  so that the other guys coding that don't understand about Graph API can easily get the objects they want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration instructions for that scenario are detailed in the documentation. Here is the link: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ASP.NET%20MVC%20Sample&referringTitle=Documentation

For a the authentication in an iFrame app you don't have to use the Javascript SDK (although you will have to use it if you are using any XFBML). All you have to do is redirect the user to the login url. We have three samples that will help you get started. The samples are CS MVC, VB WebForms, and CS WebForms.

Comment: I think i got it now! Thanks a lot!